# How to connect nodes with 45 degree and 0 degree lines (possibly via style?)

Tags: tikz-pgf

I want to connect nodes in the following way:

[image: picture of LaTeX code]

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node (foo) at (0,0) {(0,0)};
\node (bar) at (5,3) {(5,3)};

\node (baz) at (0,-1) {(0,-1)};
\node (boo) at (5,1) {(5,1)};

% What I want to happen
\draw (foo) -- ++(3,3) -- (bar);
\draw (baz) -- ++(2,2) -- (boo);

% The kind of syntax I would like, but if there is a more
% 'correct' syntax I'm happy to use it
%\draw[**magic**] (foo) -- (bar);
%\draw[**magic**] (baz) -- (boo);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I know there must be a solution with styles but my TikZ skills are currently insufficient to know how or where to look.

**How can I connect nodes in the style above?**

Comment: Kind of like a `/-` operator to parallel `|-`.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I adapted the code of [Paul Gaborits](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/14500/paul-gaborit) [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/411730/123129) to make it more general.

I used `abs` and `sign` to allow other use cases.

#### More generalized version:

With the option `to[diagonal line]` for a connection, first a **diagonal** (45°) and then a horizontal or vertical **line** is drawn. If the angle between start and end point is a multiple of 45°, only a single direct line is drawn.

**Code:**

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\tikzset{
    diagonal line/.style={
        to path={
            let \p{start}=(\tikztostart),
                \p{target}=(\tikztotarget),
                \p{diff}=({\x{target}-\x{start}}, {\y{target}-\y{start}}),
                \p{absdiff}=({abs(\x{diff})}, {abs(\y{diff})}),
                \n{mindiff}={min(\x{absdiff}, \y{absdiff})},
                \p{inter}=(
                    {sign(\x{diff}) * \n{mindiff}},
                    {sign(\y{diff}) * \n{mindiff}}
                )
            in 
                \ifnum \ifdim\x{target}=\x{start} 1
                \else \ifdim\y{target}=\y{start} 1
                \else \ifdim\x{absdiff}=\y{absdiff} 1
                \else 0\fi\fi\fi=1 %primitive tex or condition
                    -- (\tikztotarget)
                \else
                    --++ (\p{inter}) -- (\tikztotarget)
                \fi
        },
    },
}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture} 
        \foreach \d in {1,...,16} {
            \node (a\d) at ($(0,0)+(90-\d*22.5:12mm)$) {\footnotesize $a_{\d}$};
            \node (b\d) at ($(0,0)+(90-\d*22.5:35mm)$) {\footnotesize $b_{\d}$};
            \draw (a\d) to[diagonal line] (b\d);
        }
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

**Result:**

[image]

#### Older non-general version

**Code:**

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\tikzset{
    special line/.style={
        to path={
            let \p{start}=(\tikztostart), \p{target}=(\tikztotarget),
            \p{inter}=({\x{start} + sign(\x{target}-\x{start}) * abs(\y{target}-\y{start})}, \y{target})
            in -- (\p{inter}) -- (\tikztotarget)
        },
    },
}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node (x) at (0,0) {(0,0)};
        \node (y1) at (5,2) {(5,2)};
        \node (y2) at (5,-2) {(5,-2)};
        \node (y3) at (-5,-2) {(-5,-2)};
        \node (y4) at (-5,2) {(-5,2)};
        
        \draw (x) to[special line] (y1);
        \draw (x) to[special line] (y2);
        \draw (x) to[special line] (y3);
        \draw (x) to[special line] (y4);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

**Result:**

[image]

The result with Pauls or Ignasis code would be:

[image]

Comment: Fine solution! First you draw the diagonal part and then the non-diagonal part of the line. By swapping starting and ending points we get the reverse behavior. Is it possible to create a line type named `/-` or `-/` as replacement of `to[diagonal line]` and also distinguish the two situations than I mention? Thanks again for this very useful solution.

Comment: @vsantos That would be nice but seems to be difficult. You could remember this connection with first "diagonal" and then "line". One could make a second reversed style `line diagonal`. You could also rename the style, but the use of `/` or `\\` within the style name seems to be difficult as that characters have a special meaning in the definition syntax.

Answer (score 11):

Here is a solution using the `calc` TikZ library, a `let` operation and a `to path` style:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\tikzset{
  special line/.style={
    to path={
      let \p{start}=(\tikztostart), \p{target}=(\tikztotarget),
      \p{inter}=(\x{start}+\y{target}-\y{start},\y{target})
      in -- (\p{inter}) -- (\tikztotarget)
    },
  },
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

  \node (foo) at (0,0) {(0,0)};
  \node (bar) at (5,3) {(5,3)};

  \node (baz) at (0,-1) {(0,-1)};
  \node (boo) at (5,1) {(5,1)};

  \draw (foo) to[special line] (bar);
  \draw (baz) to[special line] (boo);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 7):

Not a `style` like in Paul's solution but a `command`:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone} 
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,calc}

\newcommand{\connect}[3][]{%
\draw[#1] (#2) let \p1 = ($(#3)-(#2)$) in --++(\y1,\y1)--(#3); 
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\node (a) at (0,0) {A};
\node (b) at (5,3) {B};

\connect{a}{b}

\node (c) at (0,-1) {C};
\node (d) at (5,1) {D};

\connect{c}{d}
\connect[red]{a}{d}
\connect[dashed, blue]{c}{b}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]